# File Not Found Exception with Config File

Tags: java, file-io

I am creating  web application which requires Jdbc connectivity. I want to give the db details from a config file at the present working directory. For that i created a ReadConfigFile class. When i am running this class individually it gives me the correct present working directory. however when i m running the web application from the server, it shows me an incorrect present working directory and throws FileNotFound Exception. This is my code:

```
private static final String pwd=System.getProperty("user.dir");
private static final File configFile=new File(pwd+File.separator+"configFile.txt");

private static BufferedReader br;

public static String getDBHost() {
    String dbHost=null;
    try {
        br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(configFile));
        String st;
        while((st=br.readLine())!=null) {
            if(st.trim().startsWith("DB Host: ")) {
                dbHost=st.trim().substring(9, st.trim().length());
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println(e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println(e);
    } finally {
        try {
            if(br!=null) {
                br.close();
            }               
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    return dbHost;
}
```

Can anyone tell me what to do?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use a connection pool handled by the container where your web application is running in. You do not have to care for the connection, the container does it for you.
If you only need Configuration Parameters, the web.xml is foreseen to take them and make them available in your webapplication.

As an Example with Tomcat and MySQL.
The name of my datasource will be jdbc/mydb

1) edit the file contect.xml in the directory META-INF and add

```
      <Resource auth="Container" 
      name="jdbc/mydb" 
      type="javax.sql.DataSource"              
      username="username" password="aC00l6a55w0rd" 
      driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
      url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DBNAME"/>
```

2) edit your web.xml in the directory WEB-INF and add

```
   <resource-ref>
    <description>application Database</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/mydb</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

3) within your Java code you can now get a connection from the containers connection pool. In this example I'm using JSF and a managed bean:

```
 Connection con = null;
 try {
        Context ctx = new InitialContext();
        //FacesContext fctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/mydb");
        con = ds.getConnection();

         // do some database things, like read-write-update or whatever

  } catch ( SQLException sqlex ) {
      System.out.println(getClass().getName() + " SQL Exception: " + sqlex.getMessage();
  } catch (NamingException nmex) {
        System.out.println(getClass().getName() + " Nameing Exception: " + nmex.getMessage();
  } finally (
      try {
        if ( con != null ) {
           con.close();
        }
      catch ( SQLException e) {
         System.out.println(getClass().getName() + " closing Exception: " + e.getMessage();
       }
 }
```

It is important to close all DB-Objects like ResultSet, PreparedStatement and the connection to free DB-Ressources. In fact, the connection manager does not really close the connection. And will be able to give the already opened connection to the next consumer.

Hope this helps

Comment: Can u plz tell me how can i do that?

Comment: I have added some explanation and a code snippet. Hope it helps.

Comment: Does it require any external library? There is no class for FacesContext??

Comment: You do not need the line with the facescontext. Sorry, was my fault. I took it from one of my applications, where I need the facescontext to find out the rendering phase. And yes, you minimally need the JDBC-Driver to access your database.